# Counting number of occurrences of a string inside another (Perl)

Tags: regex, perl, substring

What is the fastest way to count the number of times a certain string appears in a bigger one? My best guess would be to replace all instances of that string with nothing, calculate the difference of lengths and divide by the length of the substring, but that seems rather slow, and I need to analyze big amounts of data.

Comment: Might want to check this out... although it's from 1999, and there are most likely other ways to do this sort of thing efficiently: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=How%20can%20I%20count%20the%20number%20of%20occurrences%20of%20a%20substring%20within%20a%20string%3F

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can capture the strings, then count them. It can be done by applying a list context to the capture with `()`:

```
my $x = "foo";
my $y = "foo foo foo bar";
my $c = () = $y =~ /$x/g;  # $c is now 3
```

You can also capture to an array and count the array. Same principle, different technique:

```
my @c = $y =~ /$x/g;
my $count = @c;
```

Comment: @ronash It's the same solution. One uses a temp variable, the other does not. You could also do `my $count = @c = $y =~ /$x/g`, but instead you can simply ignore `@c` and use `()`. Which is the best, if you do not care about the actual matches.

Comment: This doesn't work if `$x` contains certain regex characters, since `$x` is interpreted as a regex. Add `\Q` to fix this, eg. `/\Q$x/g`. See `quotemeta` for more information.

Comment: Question about performance: What is the difference between `my $c = () = $y =~ /$x/g` and the (imho) prettier `my $c = scalar($y =~ /$x/g)`?  I'm guessing they're the same but I'll use the former if the latter isn't as efficient. (It's also my understanding that the `scalar()` call isn't necessary, as noted in the Brian Roach's answer below.)

Comment: @AdamKatz The difference is that the first solution works, and the second does not.

Answer (score 18):

```
my $string = "aaaabbabbba";
my @count = ($string =~ /a/g);
print @count . "\n";
```

or

```
my $count = ($string =~ s/a/a/g);
```

Comment: Erm, yes ... it's a regular expression, you can match on anything.

Comment: On your second solution, wouldn't tr/a/a/g be a better solution, because you replace the character by itself and tr is faster on that than s?

Answer (score 11):

You could use a global regex. Something like:

```
my @matches = $bigstring =~ /($littlestring)/g;
my $count = @matches;
```

Comment: That seems like the simplest solution, so I think I'll use it, unless there's a faster one? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure about the speed of regex, but I'm sure that just using matching operations is quicker than substitutions. And I can't think of a solution that doesn't have something to do with regex (it'll be very interesting to see otherwise!)

Answer (score 6):

Just for completeness you can repeatedly call the index function in a loop and count all the times it returned the index of the substring in the string, and change the starting position. That would avoid using regexes, and in my testing is a bit faster than the regex solutions.

I've adapted a sub to do that from here: http://www.misc-perl-info.com/perl-index.html

```
sub occurrences {

    my( $x, $y ) = @_;

    my $pos = 0;
    my $matches = 0;

    while (1) {
        $pos = index($y, $x, $pos);
        last if($pos < 0);
        $matches++;
        $pos++;
    }   

    return $matches;
}
```