# how to count a repeating string in a line using perl

Tags: perl

I have the below file

file1:

abc def host 123 host 869 host

I wrote below script to count the occurrence of a "host" keyword in each line.
I tried all the ways(refer the ones which are commented) still it does not seem to work. sed command worked in command line but not inside the perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(SOURCE,"</home/amp/surevy01/file1");
open(DESTINATION,"</home/amp/surevy01/file2");
while(my $line = <SOURCE>)
    {
  while(my $line1 = <DESTINATION>)
     {
        #chomp($line);
        #chomp($line1);
            if ($line =~ "host")
            {
            #my $count = grep {host} $line;
            #my $count = `sed -i {s/host/host\n/g} $line1 | grep -c {host}`;
            #my $count = `perl -pi -e 's/host/host\n/g' $line1 | grep -c host`;
            #my $count grep ("host" ,$line);
            print "$count";
            print "match found \n";
            next;
            }
           else
            {
               print "match not found \n";
               exit;
            }
      }
    }
```

I'm a beginner to perl. Looking for your valuable suggestions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting number of occurrences of a string inside another (Perl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538542/counting-number-of-occurrences-of-a-string-inside-another-perl)

Comment: This is an off topic comment but: you should use 3-argument `open` with lexical file handles and check for success (as in `open( my $fh_in, '<', $filename) or die "cannot open $filename: $!\n"`) _and_ you shouldn't name a read-only filehandle `DESTINATION`. This will only confuse you (and others) later. And please always `use strict; use warnings;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you're looping through two files in your example, but you can use the `/g` (global) flag:

```
my $line = "abc def host 123 host 869 host";

my $x = 0;
while ($line =~ /host/g){
    $x++;
}
print "$x\n"; # 3
```

When you run a regex with `/g` in scalar context (as is the conditional in the while statement), it will keep track of the location of the last match and restart from there. Therefore, `/host/g` in a loop as above will find each occurence of host. You can also use the `/g` in list contexts:

```
my $line = "abc def host 123 host 869 host";
my @matches = $contents =~ /host/g;
print scalar @matches; # 3 again
```

In this case, @matches will contain all matches of the regexp against the string, which will be ('host', 'host', 'host') since the query is a simple string. Then, scalar(@matches) will yield the length of the list.

Comment: You probably want `/\bhost\b/` to avoid, for example, matching `hosting`

Answer (score 3):

Your own solution will match instances like `hostages` and `Shostakovich`

`grep` is the canonical way to count elements of a list, and `split` will turn your line into a list of words, giving

```
my $count = grep { $_ eq 'host' } split ' ', $line
```

Answer (score 1):

This produces the number of instances of `host` in `$line`:

```
my $count = () = $line =~ /host/g;
```

But that also matches `hosting`. To avoid that, the following will probably do the trick:

```
my $count = () = $line =~ /\bhost\b/g;
```

`=()=` this is called Perl secret Goatse operator. More [info](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Goatse)